# Convolutional network for multilabel classification in NLP

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, natural-language-processing, tensorflow, multi-label-classification

I am trying to label code snippets and I base on this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01032.pdf

My dataset is just code snippets (tokenized as ascii characters) and 500 different labels from StackOverflow. Currently I have around 1,600,000 samples after filtering these with negative votes and less than 10 characters

This is my current implementation of network architecture in TensorFlow:

```
def build_cnn(config, hparams) -> tf.keras.Model:
    params = config["params"]
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1024, ))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1024, output_dim=16)(inputs)

    conv_outputs = []
    for filters, kernel in [
        (128, 2),
        (192, 3),
        (256, 4),
        (512, 5)
    ]:
        data = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel, padding="valid")(x)
        data = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(data)
        data = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel, padding="valid")(data)
        data = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: tf.reduce_sum(a, axis=1))(data)
        conv_outputs.append(data)

    # Concatenation: output size is sum of all convolution filters
    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(conv_outputs)
    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(concat_output)

    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(480, activation="relu")(concat_output)
    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(concat_output)

    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(480, activation="relu")(concat_output)
    concat_output = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(concat_output)

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation="sigmoid")(concat_output)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

As my metric I use `F1Score` from `tensorflow_addons`:

```
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=[
        F1Score(num_classes=500, average="micro", threshold=0.5, name="f1_micro"),
        F1Score(num_classes=500, average="macro", threshold=0.5, name="f1_macro"),
    ]
)
```

After 5 epochs results look like this (later it wasn't really improving):
[image]

My first idea was to apply class weights but it didn't help. Next idea was an experiment with only 10 tags (still multilabel) and this is the result:

```
{
    "step": 12,
    "loss": 0.2092941254377365,
    "f1_micro": 0.6354409456253052,
    "f1_macro": 0.5389766097068787,
    "val_loss": 0.25258970260620117,
    "val_f1_micro": 0.547073483467102,
    "val_f1_macro": 0.4620901644229889
}
```

Last thing: after I saw some results with evaluation I saw that most of the outputs are empty or only 1 class, but using smaller threshold didn't increase the metric

Any idea how to improve the model for bigger number of tags? is it the metric?